# Trying to filter data for each sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have this code :

```
Sub FilterRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Sheets(ws).Range("A1").AutoFilter
    Next
End Sub
```

I am trying to add a data filter to each sheet but I get type mismatch error.

I am new to this so any help would be great :)

Comment: Use `ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter`

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the below code

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Sheets(ws).Range("A1").AutoFilter
Next
```

here you are looping through each worksheet object, so you don't have to use

```
    Sheets(ws).Range("A1").AutoFilter
```

this is the wrong approach. sheets(ws) is wrong instead use the below method

```
    ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter  'more correct one
```

or

```
    Sheets(ws.Name).Range("A1").AutoFilter  'less correct one
```

NB: make sure all of your worksheets have data on them.